# How to make div's height responsive on all devices in chat?

Tags: html, css

While working on a chat app, I've faced an issue related to making div's height flexible. My question is how can I make `<div class="chat-body">` occupy the entire height from `<div class="chat-header">` to `<div class="chat-footer">` on all devices. I need this div to have flexible height.

```css
.chat-header {
  height: 4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e9ed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5rem;
  width: 66%;
}

.chat-body {
  max-height: 35rem;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 9rem;
  width: 66%;
}

.chat-footer {
  height: 4rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e9ed;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 contacts">This div contains list of contacts</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 pr-0 chat-area">
    <div class="row chat-header">Contacts details</div>
    <div class="row chat-body">Incoming and outgoing messages will appear here</div>
    <div class="row chat-footer">Input field, where a user types messages</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4? if so make chat-area flex with a direction of column and then make body flex-grow:1; https://www.bootply.com/JQ13dUvgVH

Answer (score 0):

If you use this on your css `@media screen and (min-width: 769px)` you can change the height on every size of screen, min-width indicates that 769px is the smallest size that the configuration you put there will affect that size of screen.

Example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .chat-footer {
    height: 70px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min width: 550px) {
  .chat-footer {
    height: 90px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeYmp.png)

Please Use this code.

```
.chat-area{
  width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 999;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.chat-header {
  padding:10px 12px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.chat-body {
    padding:10px 12px;
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.chat-footer {
  padding:10px 12px;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
```